# Wkhtmltopdf + Highcart export issue

Tags: laravel, highcharts, wkhtmltopdf

I've applied following things in my code.

For chart : Used highchart library.

For PDF export : Use wkhtmltopdf in laravel.

Till date i can export chart into pdf but yesterday ( 3rd feb 2021 ) not able to export chart into pdf. (only Charts are missed)

```
Function.prototype.bind = Function.prototype.bind || function (thisp) {
    var fn = this;
    return function () {
       return fn.apply(thisp, arguments);
    };
};
```

Above code added to pdf export view file and it works but now not works is there any idea?

Comment: Highcharts library had an update to the newest version on 2021-02-02, maybe that has an impact on it. What version of the Highcharts do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sebastian Wędzel is correct!

Please change the your js link from `https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js` to `https ://code.highcharts.com/8.0/highcharts.js`.

Faced same export issue so did this change and it works!